# subfields of a finite subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to work out all the subfield of a finite field with $3^7$ elements. So I've said that since every subfield of that field if of the form $3^n$ where $n$ is a positive divisor of $7$. so I got the finite subfields as the finite field with $3^1$ and $3^7$ elements. just wanted to check if that was right.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. ${}{}{}.$

Comment: Yes. The field $\;\Bbb F_{3^7}\;$ only has two subfields: it itself and the prime field $\;\Bbb F_3\;$

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: "So I've said that since every subfield of that field if of the form 3^n where n is a positive divisor of 7"  You might want to explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the possible sizes are $3^1$ and $3^7.$

If $m$ is the size of a subfield, then  the original field must be a finite dimensional vector space over that subfield, and thus, if $d$ is the vector space dimension, the original field must have $3^7=m^d$ elements.

This means by unique factorization that $m=3^n$ for some $n$ and $nd=7.$ This means your subfields can have $3^1$ or $3^7$ elements.

Then you need to show those subfields exist, which is easy.